# How to remove duplicates in a list without the use of dictionaries or set?

Tags: python-3.x

[code (not allowing me to paste in code here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZYqQ.png)

I am trying to create a program which sorts out words alphabetically and deletes in duplicates. For example, with Around the world, around the world, it should become ['around', 'the', 'world']. However, the output I get is ['around', 'around', 'the', 'the', 'world,', 'world.']

I am not allowed to use dictionaries or set which would make it easy to remove the duplicates. How can I remove the duplicate words without using them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is make another list to store your answer.Iterate over first list, if the word is not present in answer list append it to answer.

```
lst=['around', 'around', 'the', 'the', 'world.', 'world.']
lst2=[] ##answer list

for word in lst:

  if word not in lst2:

  lst2.append(word)

print(lst2)
```

Output

```
['around', 'the', 'world.']
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use set. If you are not supposed to use set, you could have another new list and use append.

```
listt = ['around','the','world','around','the','world']
listt2 = []

for i in listt:
     if i not in listt2:
     listt2.append(i)
print(listt2)
```